# Express middleware issue callback issue

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I got this middleware.

```
const validateInput = (req, res, next) => {
 return console.log(req.body);
};
```

When I run my server I get this error:

> Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object
> Undefined]

If I change the middleware to return a function like so:

```
const validateInput = (req, res, next) => {
 return () => console.log(req.body);
};
```

It runs but the console.log print `undefined`.

What am I missing about express rules here?
(To be clear, the middleware before this one does have a `next()` that should pass `req`)

Comment: By the error you are having, you are missing `body-parser` middleware.

Comment: Show how you are applying the middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you return? if you could give route section that would be great to debug.

if you use like this?

```
  const middleware = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    next();
  };
  route.get('/' middleware, controller);
```

Comment: Thank u. next() instead of return was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a body-parser middleware from express before you can access the body parsed version of your `request body`.

Just before handling your routes.

***app.js***

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json()); //<-- you will need express.json() middleware

app.use(require('./server/index')); //<-- here my routes middlewares are declared.

module.exports = app;
```